# Does Silverlight 4 support drag and drop from app to desktop?

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have seen that SL4 support drag and drop from the desktop to the application, but is it possible to drag and drop from the application to the desktop ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it does not support this scenario.