# I want to drag an image from a Silverlight UIElement and drop it on the users Desktop or Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, winforms, silverlight, drag-and-drop, uielement

I have a Silverlight control containing an image.  I want the user to be able to drag the image out of the Silverlight application and drop it anywhere they would be able to drop an image.  For example, to the Desktop or to a PowerPoint slide or Word document.  Everything that I have read thus far says it cannot be done but I find that hard to believe.  I'm very new to Silverlight and RIA development so any help would be much appreciated.

**Below is the code sample in my WinForm Form but the drag never starts.**

```
string[] aString = { imagePath };
DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, aString);
data.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, imagePath);
DoDragDrop(data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

Comment: How are you hosting Silverlight in WinForms?

Comment: We load the html and silverlight content in the Form.

Comment: So are you using a `WebBrowser` control, then?

Comment: Yep.  We load the html and Silverlight plugin inside a WebBrowser control.

Answer (score 4):

Well the trouble is that a drag operation in Silverlight doesn't have simple access to anything outside the browser (by design).  Depending on the user's settings you even have to get explicit permission for clipboard operations and sandboxed temporary file storage.  This really sounds like a task better suited to a WPF application (perhaps with [web deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969776.aspx)?) or some other desktop application technology.

However, that being said here are some things you could try/consider:

1. Silverlight/Javascript/ActiveX combination hosted in Internet Explorer
2. Silverlight 5 "Out of Brower" & P/Invoke (I heard P/Invoke will be supported when Silverlight 5 comes out)
3. Silverlight connecting to a web service running on the same computer (crazy, but you didn't ask for "not crazy", you asked for possible)

I am not very familiar with drag and drop in the Win32 API so it would take a lot of research and experimentation before I could confirm that this was even possible (and I can already tell you it isn't practical).

**Edit**: Based on the extra information you provided about the question I suspect it is possible to do what you are attempting.  First, are you using WPF or WinForms?  I assume WPF but one of your comments says WinForms.  I wasn't very familiar with WPF drag/drop operations, but having looked into it, I think your code is on the right path.  I created a WPF application and initiated a drag during a `KeyDown` event.  This meant that the mouse button was not necessarily pressed.  If I initiated the `DragDrop` while the button *was* down it worked.  If I initiated while the mouse button *wasn't* down, I had to push the mouse button down and the drag operation would start (this was unexpected since I assumed the mouse would have to already be down).  If I pressed the mouse down outside the application, then gave the WPF app focus (ALT+Tab), then initiated the `DragDrop` while the mouse button was still down, it didn't work.  I got a reference to the `MouseDevice` and checked the `LeftButton` property, and the state was showing as "Released" even though the button was still being held down.  It seems the key here is the way drag/drop interacts with internal mouse state.  You might have to find a way to set the mouse state (maybe with the UI Automation API?).  At this point it should be painfully obvious that this whole thing is a hack (even though it is probably possible to get it to work somehow).

Comment: Because of the Sandbox issue, I tried capturing a left mouse button down event in the code behind.  I then send the image file path to the WPF desktop form using some messaging.  In the WPF form, I initialize the dragdrop as follows. **See edited post above for code** the problem is that the drag still doesn't initialize.

Comment: Clarification.  We use WinForms to host our Silverlight plugin on Windows.  When a Left Mouse Down event occurs in the RIA, a message is sent to the Main Windows Form with the absolute file path of the image to drag.  In the Main Form, I initialize the drag using the code indicated in my original post.  I don't get any errors but the Drag doesn't work.

Comment: Interesting.  I have to admit I haven't heard of anyone hosting Silverlight in WinForms.  So you are sending the data to the desktop application, have you tried to programmatically simulate/initiate a MouseDown/MouseCapture so it acts as though the drag was initiated in the WinForms app?  That might allow you complete the drag operation.

Comment: Also gratz on breaking the sandbox, you already sound more advanced than many Silverlight developers.  +1 for thinking outside the box (pun totally intended).

Comment: Thanks Adam.  Would you be able to offer some example code to simulate the MouseDown/MouseCapture?

Comment: See updates in my answer for more info on what I have found so far.

Comment: I'm sorry for any confusion.  WinForms, not WPF.  Interesting testing results.  I will try to automate a mouse down on the Form and see if the Drag begins.

Comment: The next approach that I have been thinking about involves initiating the drag as above, copying the image to the system clipboard and then handling the drawing of the tag image as the mouse cursor moves. Then upon releasing the left mouse button performing a system paste from the clipboard. My concern with this is the potential side effects from using the clipboard and the potential problems with trying to drop onto an application window that doesn't have input focus at the time of the drop.

Comment: Are you intending to drag onto your hosting application, or do you need to be able to drag anywhere (eg. to a folder or an open MS Word document)?  If only to your hosting application that simplifies things because it opens the possibility of faking the drag drop instead of fully implementing it.

Comment: We need to drag the image anywhere.  The solution we came up with was as follows.  The RIA i.e. Silverlight sends a message to our Desktop application WinForms with the path of the image to drag along with the bounding rectangle in screen coordinates that we want to start the drag from.  The Desktop code creates and places a Panel over the area that we want to drag from.  This panel is were we use DoDragDrop to initiate the native drag when the user left clicks.  Since this panel is placed outside and above the silverlight control, everything works perfect.  Sandbox defeated.

Answer (score 2):

The solution we came up with was as follows. The RIA i.e. Silverlight sends a message to our Desktop application WinForms with the path of the image to drag along with the bounding rectangle in screen coordinates that we want to start the drag from. The Desktop code creates and places a Panel over the area that we want to drag from. This panel is where we use DoDragDrop to initiate the native drag when the user left clicks. Since this panel is placed outside and above the silverlight control, everything works perfect. Sandbox defeated.

Comment: So you got a setup that works for your application eh?  Sounds good.  I figured that you would be able to work something out.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue. My current configuration involves a Silverlight in-browser up. There upon MouseDown I setup a socket connection (maybe later I will find a better/simpler protocol - this is just first one that worked) to another standalone WinForms application. Which in response to the connection calls its own `DoDragDrop`. However the d'n'd session is without any feedback and rather unpredictable. I think it has something to do with the mouse down in browser when calling `DoDragDrop`. Could you provide more details (maybe sources?) of your solution?

Comment: I will put some source snippets together but it maybe a few days as it's been a long time since I wrote that code.  I believe the key factor was putting up a win form panel under the cursor with passed down screen coordinates and then performing the dodragdrop within that panel.

Comment: I tried that. I tried moving the cursor on the form as well. It doesn't help. (Even thou form claims that left button is down.) It seems the issue is that once the button was pressed over Silverlight (ListBox item) the mouse is somehow "stolen" or something... I tried activating the form (`Activate();`), I tried capturing the mouse (`Capture = true;`) yet nothing helps. Thanks for you support!

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on some Silverlight apps for the past few months and fully investigated your exact requirements only to find it was not possible. I believe you can drag from the file system, from Silverlight control to control, but not to the file system.

[Does Silverlight 4 support drag and drop from app to desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528904/does-silverlight-4-support-drag-and-drop-from-app-to-desktop)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772166%28v=vs.95%29.aspx