# Drag-and-Drop out of Silverlight 5 application

Tags: drag-and-drop, silverlight-5.0, out-of-browser

Is it possible to drag items (e.g. images) out of a Silverlight 5 application and drop it to another target (on desktop)? Any ideas if and how this is working? I guess this would be only possbile running the application out-of-browser with elevated trust settings enabled.

Comment: I highly doubt it's possible, as Silverlight is cross-platform (official Mac OS support at least) and that kind of stuff would be very different on Windows vs Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is possible if you have some control over what types of platform (Windows) that your users will be using. Worst case is you may need to create a helper application - see:

[I want to drag an image from a Silverlight UIElement and drop it on the users Desktop or Windows Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168357/i-want-to-drag-an-image-from-a-silverlight-uielement-and-drop-it-on-the-users-de)